# Multiple Activity Handlers for a Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I'm quite new to java and Android programming and have come across the following problem...

I've written a generic thread that sends a message over tcp to a server, waits for a response, then returns the response through a handler to the activity that started the thread.

When the activity needs to send a message to the server, it creates the thread, passing the handler in the constructor.

The handler in the activity processes the response from the server.

The issues is that there are multiple activities that will invoke this thread and each activity will handle responses differently.

For example:

In MainActivity I have a MainActivity.TcpClientHandler
In LightSettingsActivity I have a LightSettingActivitiy.TcpClientHandler

In MainActivity I invoke the thread when I need to send a message and wait a response:

```
tcpClientThread = new TcpClientThread (serverAddress,serverPort,message,tcpClientHandler);
```

In LightSettingsActivity, the same:

```
tcpClientThread = new TcpClientThread (serverAddress,serverPort,message,tcpClientHandler);
```

In my Thread class, I had to treat these as two different constructors

```
public TcpClientThread(String addr, int port,String outputMessage, MainActivity.TcpClientHandler handler)...
```

and

```
public TcpClientThread(String addr, int port,String outputMessage, LightSettingsActivity.TcpClientHandler handler)...
```

This doesn't seem very efficient and make my code kind of complex because even when sending the response back to the hander, I need to pay attention to the class that originated the thread,

Like I have to do things like this:

```
if(threadType == THREAD_MAIN)
    handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handlerMainActivity, CommonLabels.UPDATE_MSG, inputMessage));
else if(threadType == THREAD_LIGHT_SETTINGS)
    handlerLightSettings.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handlerLightSettings, CommonLabels.UPDATE_MSG, inputMessage));
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this (I tried to use callback instead of handler, but I had a whole set of other problems)?

Answer (score 0):

`TcpClientHandler` needs to be an interface. `LightSettingsActivity` and `MainActivity` need to either implement it or contain an implementation that is specific to them.

When you create a `TcpClientThread` it looks like this for all handlers

`public TcpClientThread(String addr, int port,String outputMessage,TcpClientHandler handler)...`

As for the last problem since both activities have their own implementation of `TcpClientHandler` you do not need to differentiate between them because they are unrelated. In reality using an interface in this fashion is a callback but that is generally how you solve this problem. Because you want to callback to the originator of the request not every class that happens to use `TcpClientThread`